# why cookies are removed when retrieving embedded resources in JMETER

Tags: cookies, jmeter

I'm new to JMeter so forgive me if I'm asking the obvious. I am writing a performance test for a site protected by user password, where the authentication is passed as a token in the cookies.

I am able to extract the token and add it to the pages themselves, but when using "retrieve embedded resources" it seems like the cookies are being cleared. I have a single cookie manager at the top of the thread group and the token itself is being added by a beanshell postprocessor.

Any ideas ?

Gil.

Answer (score 0):

I have never heard about cookies removal from the "embedded resources" request, looking into the [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener the cookies are present on fresh JMeter 3.0 installation

[image: JMeter Cookie Manager]

If HTTP Cookie Manager is disabled or removed I don't see this "Cookie Data"

So my expectation is that you either misconfigured something or made a mistake in your Beanshell script.

By the way, you can "tell" JMeter to store cookies as [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) by adding `CookieManager.save.cookies=true` line to *user.properties* file. See [Using the HTTP Cookie Manager in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-http-cookie-manager-jmeter-not-cookie-jar) article for more detailed information.